# Replace existing table in Word doc using python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a Word document with the following tables:

```
doc = Document('doc_generator.docx')
print(doc.tables)
```

[docx.table.Table object at 0x0000017E8B2A0D68, docx.table.Table object at 0x0000017E8B2A0198]

and I am trying to replace one of the existing tables with a new one.
What I have done is:

```
doc.tables[0] = new_table
```

with new_table being an actual Word docx table, i.e. running:

```
type(new_table)
```

returns:

docx.table.Table

If I then try to save the updated document via:

```
doc.save('Updated.docx')
```

The table is still not updated. If instead I run a command as e.g. :

```
doc.tables[0].add_row()
```

The table is actually updated in the Word doc. It seems the problem is my assignment statement. Any idea how to solve this? I do want to *replace*, not edit or update, an existing table with a new one via python-docx. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .replace method for the parent xml object:

```
doc.element.body.replace(old_table._element, new_table._element)
```

Where both 'old_table' and 'new_table' are docx.table.Table objects. The ._element attribute accesses the table object within the doc's xml structure.

If doc.element.body is not the parent element of the table, you can find the parent using:

```
old_table._element.getparent()
```